# How to use data service queries against an in-memory List in C#

Tags: c#, wcf-data-services

I have a WCF Data Service and it gets its data from dinamically created objects, like this:

```
List<UObject> list=new List<UObject>();
for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
{
list.Add(new UObject());
}
```

For the clients it has to be accessible as a queryable method, so I use this code:

```
[WebGet]
public IQueryable<UObject> GetObjects()
{
return list.Where(e=>e.Item>=2).AsQeryable<UObject>();
}
```

The problem is that the objects are in a List and it cannot be queried with Take or Skip commands, *it simply returns the entire IEnumerable (I presume)*.

So when I call it from an Android client:

```
consumer.callFunction("GetObjects").top(10).execute();
```

I get the following exception:

> org.odata4j.exceptions.BadRequestException: Query options $orderby,
>   $inlinecount, $skip and $top cannot be applied to the requested
>   resource.

How should I implement a queryable list? Is it possible or I can use it only against Entity Framework DbSets?

Answer (score 0):

Adding an attribute may resolve this problem: [Queryable], or [EnableQuery] if you are using a recent webApi bits

```
[WebGet]
[Queryable]
public IQueryable<UObject> GetObjects()
{
return list.Where(e=>e.Item>=2).AsQeryable<UObject>();
}
```

Comment: I added the WebApi package and used this attribute but I'm still getting the exception (I tested in browser with this: http://localhost:12500/DataService.svc/GetObjects?$top=3 and it also throws exception)

Comment: What is the request URI?

Comment: What do you mean? The URI is  localhost:12500/DataService.svc/GetObjects?$top=3 It is a regular OData request. Should I check anything else?